# How to convert ANN_MLP algorithm api from c to c++

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, neural-network

In c, using the ANN_MLP algorithm, i have the following code,

```
CvANN_MLP NN;
 NN.load (filename);
 cvInitMatHeader (&m_p, 1, 40, CV_32FC1, NULL);
 cvSetData (&m_p, fFeature, sizeof (float) * 40);
 CvMat *classificationResult = cvCreateMat(1, 2, CV_32FC1);
 NN.predict (&m_p , classificationResult);
```

I want to change this code to c++,
which i tried doing like this corresponding to the above code,

```
 Ptr<cv::ml::ANN_MLP> NN = cv::ml::ANN_MLP::create();
 NN = Algorithm::load<ml::ANN_MLP>(filename);
 cv::Mat m_p(1, 40, CV_32FC1, NULL);
```

Now i cannot find equivalent for `cvsetdata` in c++.Is there any other way i can do following these steps? or any resource that clears the implementation or transition of algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

See you on simple example from opencv: [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/points_classifier.cpp#L211)

Equivalent for cvSetdata is a cv::TrainData class. This class can be used in another classification algorithms.